# Vimeo player won't load on select sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-player

I have a strange problem — on some websites, if I load Vimeo's javascript player API, it's defined. On others, it's undefined.

On StackOverflow, you can open the javascript console and paste in:

```
jQuery.getScript('https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js', function () {
    alert(window.Vimeo);   
});
```

And you'll get an alert with [object Object].

If you paste that exact same code in [redbankgreen.com](http://redbankgreen.com), for example, you get an alert with "undefined."

Am I missing something obvious? The same problem exists for inclusion via `<script>` but I'm using jQuery for easy replication.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there are some some scripts defining a global `module.exports` object which Vimeo hooks into instead of defining a global Vimeo object.

So Vimeo was loaded, but in a module.exports object left behind by another script.